# Printing the same values for all families

Tags: java

Ok, so i was given this project in class and i was able to create most of it. The only thing I am stuck on is the income output for n families. It keeps on printing the same outcome for each family. I have no idea why is it doing that.. Any help would be great. Thank You.

```
public class Family {

private double income;
private int size;

public Family()//set everything to 0 at first
  {
      income=0.0;
      size=0;
  }

public Family(double newIncome, int newSize)
  {
      income=newIncome;
      size=newSize; 
  }

public void writeoutput()
  {
      int index = 0;//created variable for an array 

      System.out.println("how manny Families are there");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      index=input.nextInt();
      int[]family=new int[index];//input how many families 

  } 
      for (int i=0;i<index;i++){

        System.out.println("Enter income in family["+i+"]");
        income=input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter size in family["+i+"]");
        family[i]=input.nextInt();//input amount of members

    }

    System.out.println("Values in array: ");

    for (int i=0;i<index;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Family["+i+"] has $"+this.income+" dollars for incom");
        }

    for (int i=0;i<index;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Family["+i+"] has "+family[i]+" members");
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT

```
      how manny Families are there
      3
      Enter income in family[0]
      43.2
      Enter size in family[0]
      5
      Enter income in family[1]
      653.5
      Enter size in family[1]
      8
      Enter income in family[2]
      234.5
      Enter size in family[2]
      6
      Values in array: 
      Family[0] has $234.5 dollars for incom
      Family[1] has $234.5 dollars for incom
      Family[2] has $234.5 dollars for incom
      Family[0] has 5 members
      Family[1] has 8 members
      Family[2] has 6 members
```

Comment: Are you sure entering families should be in that the `Family` class?  What is calling this code?  It may be better design to have `writeOutput` only write its own output, not ask for input as well

Comment: This code doesn't compile. You have statements outside methods. Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46854487/edit).

Comment: No worries I have it working now.. Thanks

Comment: @DenisJones Where are you using member variables size and income or even the constructors. You are not using ant OOP features. Code is redundant here.

Comment: @DenisJones, getting it working is not what programming learning is about.  You have to get it working the right way.  Formatting and readability are important as well.

Answer (score 1):

I will not give you whole solution. But you have lot of flaws on your code.

Where are you using member variables `size` and `income` or even the constructors. You are not using any OOPs features. Code is redundant here.

Instead of using `int[]family=new int[index];` use `Family families[] = new Family[index]` and store data on the member variables `income` and `size`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you look to be learning arrays of objects, your famili[] should be

```
Family[] family = new Family[index];
```

Then in your loop

```
family[i] = new Family();
family[i].income = input.nextDouble();
family[i].size = input.nextInt();
```

And on the print output last part you access the variables trough family[position].variable